# Selenium Server: Windows Service: The Hard Disk Filled Up After a Few Days

Tags: java, windows, selenium, service

I have used [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to create a Windows Service for my **Selenium Server** instance (**v 2.48.2 of the Selenium Server Standalone JAR**).

I have also set the service to log on as a Local System Account, and have allowed the service to interact with the desktop. When I have used a particular account for the service, instead of the local system account, Internet Explorer would not launch.

I noticed that after a few days, the hard disk would start filling up with temporary internet files at the following location:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5
```

After a few days, I saw that the size of this folder was ~30 GB. I have had to manually clear out this folder.

I've used the following command to create the service:

```
nssm install seleniumhub java -jar C:\selenium-server\selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\selenium-server\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium-server\IEDriverServer.exe
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Are you calling `driver.dispose()`  in the end of each run?

Comment: I am not seeing the dispose() method in the Java APIs. I am currently using FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, and RemoteWebDriver; none of them have a dispose() method on them

Comment: C# code sorry. In java its `driver.quit();`

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah, I'm calling driver.quit();

Answer (score 0):

It's a common occurrence that you clean the tmp directory because everytime a new profile is made, a folder is put in by Chrome/IE/FF that stores information about that session.

You should write a simple script to clear this folder after every test suite is run. Something along this pseudo-code will work:

```
for $dir in %TMP%:
    rm -fr $dir
```

Comment: Hmm, that could work, however I would have to trigger the cleanup remotely. My tests are currently running on a CI server (Jenkins), and the Windows box is used as a remote selenium server

Comment: or just put a cleanup task on the windows box that occurs every 30 minutes or something.  you could check to see if a browser window is open to make sure you aren't clearing the folder of an existing session

Comment: Is there a way that you would recommend to programmatically check if a browser instance is open?

Comment: since you are on windows, just grep the  `tasklist` command for `iexplore`, `chrome` or `firefox`

Answer (score 0):

So in order to avoid this problem, running the Selenium Server as a startup process, instead of as a service, seems to not fill the hard disk up.